# Using words from the Dictionary

Tags: definition

In the oxford dictionary, the [definition of colonize](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/colonize) is

> Send settlers to (a place) and establish political control over it.

An example sentence with this definition is

> I think we should send them to colonize other planets for us.

I have been told that you can substitute the definition of a word for the word. The thing is that it wouldn't make sense for this sentence. It would be 'I think we should send them to send settlers to other planets for us and establish political control over it.' What is the rule for knowing when a word fits in a situation?

Answer (score 2):

You should adapt your sentence accordingly, in other words, in this case, just delete the unnecessary words:

> I think we should send settlers to other planets for us and establish political control over it.

As you can see I just simply deleted **send them to**.

Answer (score 1):

Words have multiple definitions listed in dictionaries - and generally more closely related but slightly different definitions that any given dictionary doesn't list. You can take dictionary definitions as suggestions of what a word might mean in any given context, but you can't be sure simply by reading the dictionary.

Sometimes one of the definitions given will be the relevant one, but you may have to guess which it is. Sometimes none will be quite right. That's why learning languages is hard.

The [lexico page that you linked](https://www.lexico.com/definition/colonize) to offers other definitions for colonize, including:

> Appropriate (a place or domain) for one's own use.

You can substitute this into your sentence, skipping the parenthetical remark from the lexicographer:

> I think we should send them to **appropriate for one's own use** other planets for us.

You still need to edit slightly the sentence slightly to make it make sense and remove duplication:

> I think we should send them to **appropriate for** our **own use** other planets.

and you can move the subject of the verb appropriate inside the phrase:

> I think we should send them to **appropriate** other planets **for** our **own use**.